# Match timestamp with preg_match

Tags: php, timestamp, preg-match

I have this regular expression right now and it's just printing out 1: `^[0-9]{10,15}$^`. I want to see if there is any timestamp in the filename (for example 3843_1328414035.jpg) or not. What do I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got an error if I didn't had any ^at the end.

Comment: Please replace `^` with `/`. It's confusing because `^` is normally used to indicate 'the beginning' but you're using it as a delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have this preg_match statement

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/(\d{10})/","1234_1328414035.jpg",$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

or simply check if pattern exists

```
if(preg_match("/(\d{10})/","1234_1328414035.jpg")) {echo "found";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using the return value, instead of the `&$matches` array.

All of this taken from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> preg_match() returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because preg_match() will stop searching after the first match.

To get the matched text:

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Comment: Oh. Okej. What should I use for function to make this possible? :)

Comment: Edited to add proposed solution.